# How was Moody captured by Wormtail and Barty Crouch Jr?

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters, barty-crouch-jr

At the start of *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, how was Alastor Moody captured?  Why was he able to be captured by Wormtail and Barty Crouch Jr?  After all Alastor Moody was the most powerful Auror, and single-handedly captured dozens of Death Eaters.

Also, didn't he place protective enchantments around his own home?

Comment: "Moody put up a struggle. There was a commotion. We managed to subdue him just in time" - Crouch Jr says it fairly plainly. It wasn't easy but they did it

Comment: Let's see. 1 Moody vs 1 Wormtail and 1 Jr = 2 people. 1 vs 2. That's a serious disadvantage in a fight. Assuming for a minute that magical duels are strictly only won by the more powerful mage (I don't think that's ever established), where do you get the information that he is more "powerful" than both of them combined?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170690/why-couldnt-moody-beat-crouchs-imperius?rq=1

Comment: But Moody was the most powerful auror that had served the Ministry of Magic...

Comment: @Ken_To_2018 Have you been able to see some of the comments on your other questions about your question titles?

Answer (score 28):

## Moody did fight, but Barty Crouch Jr. and Wormtail subdued him.

Barty Crouch Jr. describes how he and Wormtail captured Moody while being questioned under Veritaserum. He says that Moody struggled, and there was a commotion, but they did still manage to subdue him. From this, it sounds like it was difficult to capture Moody, though they were able to.

> “Wormtail and I did it. We had prepared the Polyjuice Potion beforehand. We journeyed to his house. Moody put up a struggle. There was a commotion. We managed to subdue him just in time. Forced him into a compartment of his own magical trunk. Took some of his hair and added it to the Potion. I drank it, I became Moody’s double. I took his leg and his eye. I was ready to face Arthur Weasley when he arrived to sort out the Muggles who had heard a disturbance. I made the dustbins move around the yard. I told Arthur Weasley I had heard intruders in my yard, who had set the dustbins off. Then I packed up Moody’s clothes and Dark detectors, put them in the trunk with Moody, and set off for Hogwarts.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 35 (Veritaserum)*</sup></sub>

In addition, Barty Crouch Jr. had the Polyjuice Potion so he was able to drink it quickly and then (as Moody) convince Arthur Weasley that everything was fine.

Answer (score 4):

### Even Mad-Eye Moody's famed paranoia has limits - apparently rodent proofing his house exceeded them.

From an entirely unrelated series:

> “You want to send in harnessed ferrets through a laundry vent?” Augustine clearly had difficulty coming to terms with that idea.
>   
>   “Yes,” Cornelius said.
>   
>   I blinked. “Wouldn’t the vent be secured by an alarm?”
>   
>   The three of them looked at me as if I’d suddenly sprouted a second head.
>   
>   “It doesn’t make sense to secure a laundry vent,” Rogan explained. “It’s too small and it opens into a dryer.”
>   ...
>   ...
>   
>   “I’m more paranoid than Baranovsky,” Rogan said. “My laundry vents aren’t secured. But I’d imagine there is a metal grate over them.”
>   
>   “Does anybody else find this whole idea of a ferret heist mildly absurd?”   Augustine looked around the room.
>   
>   “Grates are not an issue,” Cornelius said.
>   
>   “Can your animals handle screws?” Augustine asked.
>   
>   Cornelius met his gaze. “Let’s assume that I spend as much time training my animals and honing my magic as you do practicing your illusions.”
>   
>   “How confident are you that this will work?” I asked Cornelius.
>   
>   He smiled at me.
>   
>   “Let’s do it,” Rogan said.
>   
> <sub><sup>*- White Hot, by Ilona Andrews*</sup></sub>

As an intelligent rodent, Wormtail possess unparalleled advantages when it comes to breaking and entering.  Once he was inside, he could disable the alarms and let Crouch in.  He probably wouldn't be able to turn off everything, but all he needs to do is get Crouch in fast enough to get the jump on Moody before he's fully awake.  Two fully prepared wizards against one half-asleep one is no contest, even if the half-asleep wizard is Alastor Moody.  Even so, he put up enough of a fight to be noticed by the neighbors, which is pretty impressive.

Comment: But how come Mad Eye Moody didn't fetch help from the Ministry?  Apparently he was attacked... he should have contacted the auror office... or even summon Remus Lupin for help...

Comment: @Ken_To_2018 He didn't have time.  Besides, Moody is paranoid and used to acting on his own.  His first instinct would be to fight rather than to call for help.

Comment: I'm confused how the quoted passage helps.